# Force JS to load on page load

Tags: javascript, geolocation, reload

i am trying to get a page to load using Geobytes.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background: transparent; border: none;">
<script src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?pages=US&ext=html&after=-1" language="Javascript"></script><script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)!="undefined"&&sGeobytesLocationCode.indexOf('US')==0)
{
    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='06; URL=http://www.example.com'>");
}
// ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?  I can get function onload to work since its a popup window.

Comment: *cant (sorry for the typo)

Comment: By the way, you can edit the question instead of commenting.

Comment: An onload function is not required.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event fires when all the content on your page fully loads including the DOM (document object model) content, asynchronous javascript, frames and images.

You can also use the `DOMContentLoaded` event instead (faster) when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
<script>
// For legacy browsers use this instead: window.onload = function()
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)!="undefined" && sGeobytesLocationCode.indexOf('US')==0)
  {
    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='06; URL=http://www.example.com'>");
  }

}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?pages=US&ext=html&after=-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>

            function after_load() {
                if (typeof (sGeobytesLocationCode) != "undefined" && sGeobytesLocationCode.indexOf('US') == 0)
                {
                    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='06; URL=http://www.example.com'>");
                }                
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="after_load()" style="background: transparent; border: none;">
    </body>
</html>
```